# CVS commit - sending changes to old repository

Tags: linux, centos, cvs

We are running CVS to manage some shell scripts in the department. The cvs repository previously ran on our server `lynx` in the directory /export/data/cvs/ . I have rsynced this data to a second server `jaguar` in the directory `/export/data/cvs/`. I have updated the environmental variable `CVSROOT=jaguar:/export/data/cvs`. When I do a cvs checkout on a machine the data comes from jaguar:/export/data/cvs/. However when I `cvs commit` and changes these are commited to `lynx:/export/data/cvs`. Are there other configuration files to change the destination of `cvs commit`

We are running cluster of rhel5 machines which are currently being upgraded to CentOS6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CVS records the root information in the `Root` file in *every* checked out directory (within the `CVS` directory). You need to change it all of those files.

`find . -name Root` from the top of the checkout working directory should find them all.

Comment: There is a `CVSROOT` dir which has multiple files all of which are completely commented out

Comment: Not on the server. In the checkouts.